# Change a .dll file on runtime in C# and communicate between two .dlls

Tags: c#, dll

I would like to build a server application, with an up-time almost at 100%.
The application will be build in C#, and will be using modules (.dll-files) with functionality within.

If I at a given point decides to add some functionality, or fix a bug, in a module, I would like *not* to close the application, overwrite the .dll-file and then restart the application. 
If I could just stop the module, update it, and resume - it would be great!

What I am looking for is the Component/Service Configurator design pattern for C#.
It works as shown on the figure below:

[image]

The  `ComponentRepository` can register `Component`s, load them into the application with `init()`, pause them with `suspend()`, unload them with `fini()`, and resume them with `resume()`.

The application will load the module, run it until I have an update for a module, pause and suspend the module, overwrite the existing, and load the new module.

[Microsoft Prism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405479%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) can load the modules, but as they note in a small box:

> After a module is loaded and initialized, the module assembly cannot be unloaded.

An also [mentioned here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173101.aspx):

> There is no way to unload an individual assembly without unloading all
>   of the application domains that contain it.

So the option suggested by Microsoft is, that the [application creates an `AppDomain`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5b8a8f9.aspx) and uses it, the unloads it later on.

**The question**:

If I created a separate `AppDomain` for each module I use, how do I communicate between them? Will [MVVM Light's `Messenger`](http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/WP8/html/9fb9c53a-943a-11d7-9517-c550440c3664.htm), or [Prism's `EventAggregator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) work?

Comment: maybe take a look at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687245/use-appdomain-to-load-unload-external-assemblies

Comment: @montewhizdoh - that looks promissing. I shall post an answer when I have tried it.

Comment: maybe peek at this, too http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42312/Loading-Assemblies-in-Separate-Directories-Into-a

Comment: I cant find the DOCO for this one anymore, but I think this could be worth a look, too. https://github.com/UAV/PlugInLoader